# How to handle mongodb nodejs error in find

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I call `collection.find(someBadQuery)` and I get an error from MongoDB. But it ends up as unhandled rejection. How to handle this rejection?
As described in [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/Next/classes/Collection.html#find) For `find()` MongoDB NodeJS driver returns `FindCursor` and not promise, therefore `.catch()`, or async try ... catch will not work. It is EventEmmiter, but there is no `error` event.

**Is there any way how to track which `.find()` call caused the error?**

The error is for example:

```
Unhandled rejection:  MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: data.Users__UserRole index: title_1 dup key: { title: null }
    at ...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:53:33
    at ...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:277:25
    at ...
    at handleOperationResult (...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:335:20)
    at Connection.onMessage (...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:222:9)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at processIncomingData (...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:132:20)
    at MessageStream._write (...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:391:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:332:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:336:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
```

So how can I prevent unhandled rejections and actually trace query which causes the error? Where should I put error handler?
Thanks.

Comment: Cursor iterator is async. `find` initiates the search request, driver retrieves the data, and `cursor` makes it available on application level.  What was the error?

Comment: Doesn't matter what was the error, I want to catch it and work further with it, but I cannot attach any error handler anywhere.

Comment: Well, it does, as it may help answering "where should you put" the try-catch. If you want to catch **any** error - `process.on('uncaughtException', handler)` but there is little you can do at this point but exit the process. I

Comment: Lol, that's exactly why the error matters. Please read what it says - " E11000 duplicate key error ...  operations\insert.js:53:33" - it happens on **insert**, not **find**. You are trying to insert a new user with the same title as the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

To get `Promise` you need to call `.toArray()` on that `FindCursor`.

```
const findResult = await collection.find({}).toArray();
console.log('Found documents =>', findResult);
```

as mentioned in [docs](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find-all-documents)

Comment: But the error occurs sooner than `toArray()`

Comment: You can try this syntax to code the `collection.find` and `cursor.toArray` as two statements - and have the code in a _try-catch_ block: [Access Data from Cursor](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/#return-an-array-of-all-documents). Also, see [Error Handling](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.8/#error-handling).

Comment: @MáriusRak can you share that error message & stacktrace

Comment: I've added the error to the question

Comment: @MáriusRak its duplicate key error, you have 2 or more `Doc`s with same key (in this case `UserRole` db has 2 or more `Doc` with `title`  = `null`).  To fix this delete one or all of them having `title=null`, and make sure title is not null when you are creating new role.

Comment: I know what the error means. That's not my question, please read my question.

Comment: @MáriusRak ah got it, I think its from ```client.connect()```, try adding `try/catch` or `.catch` to it.

Comment: Well, is there any way to track which `.find()` call caused the issue?